# updating tizen-2.1 on test device

Tags: vmware, tizen

I have trouble on updating tizen-2.1 on my test device

I follow manual step by step, but some errors when I use lthor tool.

Can you give me some insight?

my environment

```
    current tizen version on test device => 2.0
    ubuntu 13.04 (on vmware 9)
    modemmanager off
```

Error Message:

```
    line 345: failed to read signature bytes
    line 629: handshake failed
    line 958: failed to open port (null)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please follow these steps

I updated my device by following these steps.

https://wiki.tizen.org/wiki/Flash_Tizen_2.1_Image_to_Reference_Device

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunatelly, sometimes it's needed to uninstall modemmanger at all:

```
sudo apt-get purge modemmanager
```

Also VMWare may be at the bottom of your problem.